# Microsoft Outlook 2011 for MAC, could not send email?

Tags: email, ms-office

I am getting "Mail Delivery Failed" messages for some of the
emails sent.

As I am replying an email, I am sure that there isn't any misspelling on the recipient's email address.

A typical message below.

On 22/06/2015 9:47 am, "Mail Delivery System"
 wrote:

> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>   recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>   ...

Any help would be very much appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One of the recipient used a corrupt email address, you are going to have to check them

Comment: The interesting part of the delivery failed-message is a few lines below the part you've included already, can you include that as well?

Comment: This is the full message: On 22/06/2015 10:47 pm, "Mail Delivery System"
><Mailer-Daemon@web1.hosting-server-dns.com> wrote:
>
>>This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>>
>>A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
>>recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>>
>> sample@sample.com
>> host something.something.net [000.0.00.0]
>> SMTP error from remote mail server after RCPT
>>TO:<somebody@somewhere.com>:
>> 553 IP 11.11.111.1 is UCEPROTECT-Level 1 listed. See
>>http://www.uceprotect.net/rblcheck.php?ipr=22.22.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the mail was sent from a disposable e-mail address. If that's the case then mail sending will be failed.

Answer (score 0):

The error is on their end, not yours, and that is where the response is coming from. The best you can do is contact the intended recipient via another method and have them check their email account.